# SharedPreference returning null flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to render something from Shared Preferences.

Here is my code :

```
return FutureBuilder<ChildModel>(
      future: sharedPreference.getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print("SNAPSHOT" + snapshot.data.toString());
        if (snapshot.hasData &&
            snapshot.data != null) {
          return _render(snapshot,context);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        } else {
          return Text('Select Vehicle');
        }
      },
    );
```

My SharedPreferece:

```
Future<ChildModel> getData() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    ChildModel singleObject ;
    List<ChildModel> userVehicleList = [];

    getSelectedVehicleID().then((onValue){
      if(onValue!=null){
        if (prefs.get(_kUserVehicles) != null) {
          final List parsedList = json.decode(prefs.get(_kUserVehicles));
          userVehicleList =  parsedList.map<ChildModel>((val) =>  ChildModel.fromJson(val)).toList();
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < userVehicleList.length; i++) {
          if (userVehicleList[i].id == onValue) {
            singleObject = userVehicleList[i];
          }
        }
      }
    });

    return singleObject ?? null;
  }
```

The problem is `singleObject = userVehicleList[i]` is executed but doesnt return anything.

Always `snapshot.data` is null in Future Builder.

I want to return that singleObject that I found in that loop.

Can Anyone please help me with this ???

Comment: where is the part where you are saving to shared preference ?

Comment: I am not saving this I am just getting the matched object from the list. The list saving and returning of list is working fine.

Comment: may be you are trying to retrieve data  but their is no data with the key. add ?? like this and try.  final List parsedList = json.decode(prefs.get(_kUserVehicles) ?? 0);

Answer (score 1):

You are not awaiting for future to finish before returning value.

So

```
    return singleObject ?? null;
```

will execute before

```
getSelectedVehicleID()
```

What you need is

```
int _selectedVehicleId = await getSelectedVehicleID();
```

And then continue getting anything from shared preferences and returning that.

Hope that will help :)